# django-pdb: --pdb invalid argument

Tags: python, django

I'm just installing django for the first time and I am having problems getting django-pdb to work with a test project I have setup. I followed the directions at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pdb, adding the appropriate information to my settings.py and when I try to run: manage runserver --pdb or --ipdb, I get the following:

```
usage: manage.py runserver [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                           [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                           [--traceback] [--no-color] [--ipv6] [--nothreading]
                           [--noreload] [--nostatic] [--insecure]
                           [addrport]
manage.py runserver: error: unrecognized arguments: --ipdb
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

So yeah.. I might have lied a little about reading the directions.  I have django 1.8 installed and had placed django_pdb at the end of the installed_apps list.  django.contrib.staticfiles was before it in the list and was probably overwriting django_pdb's modifications to manage.py ... Moving django_pdb to the top fixed the problem.